# Given there is no primary on the democratic side, why isn't there a push to get Democrat voters to vote Trump out in the primary?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, presidential-election, primaries, joe-biden

Biden is the incumbent with no serious challenges.

Given his unpopularity with Democrats, why hasn't there been a campaign run by Democrats or maybe even some anti-Trump Republicans to get Democrat voters to vote in the Republican primary and vote Trump out?

In fact, given that the incumbent is generally never challenged, why doesn't this happen at every election? Why wouldn't the opposition primary be largely influenced by voters from both parties? For any voter, if you had to vote in only one primary, you should pick the primary where your vote mattered?

Comment: "get Democrats voters to vote in the Republican primary" How would that work? I don't know how the primaries work exactly. Can you just go there, say that you are a Republican and want to vote for X? What if they say, no you're not Republican. Do I have to prove it somehow.

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution you would have to register as Republican first, in most cases, but that’s fairly simple to do. The first primary I participated in, I wasn’t affiliated, so they just asked me “hey which party?” and then registered me there. IIRC switching affiliation just needs enough time before the election

Comment: @fyrepenguin Whether you can vote in a given primary depends on the state.  In some states, you must be registered as a member of the party.  In others you do not but you can only vote in one primary.  I don't know if there's a state that allows you to vote in as many primaries as you like but I don't think there's anything preventing it.

Comment: @JimmyJames well yes that’s my point - given time before the primary, you can just change to the affiliation that you want to vote in the primary of. I’m not talking about voting in multiple. Like I said, “switching affiliation”.

Comment: Saddening that the answer apparently isn't "because that's not what a democracy does".

Comment: @DonQuiKong, I wouldn't be so harsh.  There are many democracies that don't have closed primaries, or have a runoff system that removes the need for primaries.  The fact that many states have closed primaries could be argued as anti-democratic and skirting the rules actually makes it more democratic. In some cities, you have no voice in the mayoral election unless you are registered Democrat.

Comment: @JoelFan sabotaging another party doesn't sound very democratic to me.

Comment: @DonQuiKong, I agree that outright sabotage is anti-democratic, but registering for a party you would never vote for in a general election, just so you can vote in the primaries seems valid.

Comment: @JoelFan if the only motivation is sabotage? It's an ethical question, not a legal one.

Comment: @DonQuiKong "because that's not what a democracy does" It didn't happen so far, so it's not what the US did, but we don't know if only because of laziness or conviction or what the future might bring. The only sure thing is that rules alone can never protect a democracy.

Comment: @DonQuiKong Is voting for a candite that you think should be representing a party or voting against one you think shouldn't be representing that party even if you don't plan on supporting them later really sabotage? In the end doesn't that help the other party by making it more likely to get your support?

Comment: I'm tempted to fix the grammatically incorrect use of "Democrat" in the question title, but in the end I think it supplies very useful information about where the poster is coming from with the question.

Comment: Ultimately only a small percentage of the population is politically active enough to participate in such a scheme that it wouldn't change the numbers.

Comment: There are reasons to vote in "the other party's" primary other than sabotage. In fact, you could do it in a way that's arguably the _opposite_ of sabotage: voting for a more moderate candidate, in the hope that you're able to bring the party closer to the center so that in the case that your preferred candidate doesn't win in the general election, the person who does win is a bit closer to your liking (and probably the liking of many of the other voters who voted for the losing candidate). Seen in that light, it's not an act of sabotage but a building of consensus.

Comment: @yshavit "Seen in that light, it's not an act of sabotage but a building of consensus." Maybe it could be seen as such but surely not by the members of the other party. For them it would simply be outsiders interfering in their party-wide nomination process. And I doubt they would welcome the interference even if meant well somehow. One could say that everything that is not forbidden is allowed but then decency doesn't need to exist anymore, only rules.

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution They could see it as unwelcome interference, but they'd be incorrect to call it "sabotage" if there's no intention to destroy.

Comment: @yshavit Supporters of Donald Trump would call it sabotage because the intention is to destroy his candidacy.

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution By that reasoning, a lifelong Republican who votes for Haley is also sabotaging the Republican primary, as that vote seeks to destroy Trump's candidacy. If the point of the primary is to pick the candidate, and someone votes in that primary without the intention of harming the party, then it's hard to see how that's sabotage. You can't presuppose that the best thing for the party is to nominate Trump, or else why even have the primary?

Comment: @yshavit I make a distinction (only Republicans vote in Republican primaries) where you do not make one. Of course we end up with different results. You can call it the opposite of sabotage, others can call it sabotage. Just reflects different viewpoints.

Answer (score 28):

Joe W's answer is a good frame challenge that refutes the question's premise (i.e. that the Democrats aren't holding primaries), but I'd like to focus on the question itself:

> why hasn't there been a campaign [...] to get Democrat voters to vote in the Republican primary and vote Trump out?

Firstly, and most importantly, **this isn't possible in most states**. [Per Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_election#United_States), only 14 states have "open primaries" in which registered Democrats can vote in the Republican primary (and vice versa). 16 others allow unaffiliated voters to vote in whichever primary they like, though I assume they would no longer be considered "unaffiliated" afterwards, and thus the trick would only work once per voter.

Secondly - and this brings me on to one of your other questions -

> why doesn't this happen at every election? Why wouldn't the opposition primary be largely influenced by voters from both parties?

...it *has* been tried in the past, *and it didn't work*. Again, [quoting Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossover_voting#Party_raiding), which calls the practice "party raiding":

> A notable example of attempted party raiding was Operation Chaos in the Democratic primary in 2008, when Rush Limbaugh encouraged Republicans to vote for Hillary Clinton in an effort to weaken Barack Obama politically. The effort was ultimately unsuccessful. Another occurred in the 2012 Republican primaries, where many Democratic voters in Michigan voted for weaker GOP candidate Rick Santorum over front-runner Mitt Romney in order to disrupt his campaign. This attempt was also unsuccessful.

I expect that the number of opposition-party voters willing and able to go through with the raid simply wasn't enough to make a difference, and given that [Trump is consistently polling about 50 percentage points higher than any other Republican candidate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nationwide_opinion_polling_for_the_2024_Republican_Party_presidential_primaries#Nationwide_polling), the chances of a party raid against him being successful are practically nil.

Thirdly, as JMS stated, Trump (despite his popularity within the Republican Party) is hardly the most appealing candidate himself, and has already lost to Biden once before. It's likely that many Democrats want him to win the nomination in the belief that, in a presidential shootout between Trump and Biden, Biden will win just as he did in 2020.

Comment: It seems unlikely, but the possibility of the Republican candidate not being eligible to run would seem like an advantage for Democrats, even in safe states where it would help in down-ballot races.

Comment: I know people who register for a party they do not support so that they can vote in its primary.

Comment: It's possible, even in the 22 States with closed primaries, because voters can easily switch registration.  It just requires some planning.  (Also, this doesn't really affect the answer, but unaffiliated voters remain unaffiliated even after they choose to vote in a partisan primary, because that choice doesn't affect their registration.  But even if it did, they could unaffiliate again.)

Comment: @TobyBartels what is the advantage of being affiliated then? As a voter I would much rather stay unaffiliated and decide on an election by election where I would use my vote

Comment: Good answer, maybe add one further point: Voting against Trump in the primaries might backfire. If this gets noticed (and with the number of votes required, it will be noticed), it is fodder for his propaganda machine, likely rallying the Republicans around him. So, even if they are successful in one or two states, they will be outvoted in the following primaries.

Comment: @Pollman, in states with "closed primaries", unaffiliated voters are not allowed to vote in any primaries.

Comment: @Pollman :  That's what I do!  But closed primaries were the rule for a long time (and still are in many States), and a lot of people have emotional attachments to their parties (plus if you actually want to get involved in politics, then being a longtime member of a major party helps).  And conversely, in the States with open primaries, it doesn't matter if or how you're affiliated.  But some people definitely do switch registration (where the primaries are closed) or just stay unaffiliated and pick whichever ballot they want at the election (in the intermediate States where that's a thing).

Comment: Agree with @TobyBartels, an affiliated voter can typically change their affiliation as frequently as they want, in some cases they just can't do it very close to the primary itself. I don't think there's anything in any state that prevents a registered Democrat from re-registering as a Republican, voting in the R primary, and then switching their registration back to D. I disagree with the bolded statement that "this isn't possible in most states" - it would be very strange for a voter to be *unable* to change which party they affiliate with!

Comment: Operation Chaos was, in fact, remarkably successful.  Not that it allowed Hillary to win, but because Obama likely would have had the the nomination wrapped up much earlier in the process.  The huge amount of resources that were used by both the Obama and Clinton campaigns fighting each other in the primary were resources that would have been used in the general election.

Comment: In Massachusetts, an unaffiliated ("unenrolled", as it's called here) candidate can vote in either primary, but can only vote in one of them. They are not automatically enrolled in that party, and come next primary they can again pick whichever they want. From a voting perspective, there is absolutely no benefit in registering with a party, and in fact [about 61% of voters are unenrolled](https://www.sec.state.ma.us/divisions/elections/download/research-and-statistics/enrollment_count_20230201.pdf) despite it being a solidly blue state. …

Comment: … In other words, they're unenrolled but reliably vote for the Democrats in the general election. As to why anyone would then register with a party: I'm not sure, but I suspect most of it is a mix of "to show support" and "I didn't know I didn't have to." You do need to be registered with the party to vote for its officers (or be one), but that's a pretty wonky thing that most people don't do.

Answer (score 12):

> **Question:**
>
> Given there is no primary on the democratic side, there isn't there a push to get Democrat voters to vote Trump out in the primary?

**Short Answer**

Because the Democrats like their chances against former President Trump.

**Answer**

There is an old political axiom:  When your opponent is shooting himself in the foot, don't interfere.  Given that truism, why would the Democrats obstruct Trump from getting the Republican nomination?  Trump is pretty much their ideal opposition candidate:

- A legally defined sex predator / rapist
- 3 courts have now found President Trump engaged in insurrection
- Betrayed his oath of office
- out on bail currently in 3 different jurisdictions not related to the ones previously mentioned
- currently facing around 100 felony charges
- likes to quote Adolf Hitler (vermin indeed)
- confuses President Biden and President Obama during rallies
- won't be able to campaign in April or March because he will be in court every day
- independents hate him
- a sizeable number of Republicans hate him (not the majority)
- 60% disapproval rating (folks who strongly object to him and folks who won't consider voting for him)
- will probably be convicted of at least one felony before the general election
- may even be in prison in Nov 2024 or shortly thereafter.

While the Republicans have underperformed in every election cycle since President Trump won in 2016, probably the single biggest issue in 2024 will be the same issue which was most responsible for Republicans underperforming in 2022 interim elections. Dobbs vs Jackson.  For decades, abortion rights were a great republican wedge issue.  It spoke to social Conservatives, and social liberals didn't vote the issue as strongly because Roe vs Wade was established law.  Now that it has been overturned it has become a very important motivating issue for women, even women who traditionally vote Republican.  The Dems have video of President Trump taking credit for overturning it.  It's an albatross around the necks of the Republican party in general and Donald Trump specifically and probably will be the single biggest issue in the 2024 campaign.  The GOP has a lot of systemic issues at this point.

When President Trump narrowly won the 2016 election a lot of pundits said Hillary Clinton was the only candidate he could have defeated.  I think the Democrats and President Biden are very happy to run against former President Trump.  Their nightmare would be to run against a younger candidate with less baggage.

Comment: Every one of your bullet points make Trump more appealing, not less, for many voters. They are spun as evidence of Democrat election-stealing tactics, which makes voters more motivated to "fight back".

Comment: @JoelFan  The key point there, is that Trump's legal issues make him more attractive to people who are already highly likely to vote for him, and un-attractive to people who were already unlikely to vote for him, so the question is how he appears to 'floating voters' - my guess would be that they would mostly disapprove.

Comment: @joelFan  Being a rapist, seditionist, and felon (if convicted)  doesn't make him "more appealing" to anybody.   I would say these unprecedented legal troubles don't matter to some, perhaps many of his followers.   They certainly matter to moderates and independents necessary to get re-elected.

Comment: The [polls](https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/polls/president-general/) seem to disagree: Trump is the only Republican candidate who polls higher than, or at least equally to, Biden. Both DeSantis and Haley are behind against Biden. While this is a feel-good post about bashing Trump, its underlying premise doesn't hold.

Comment: @Riwen,  If you check with RealClearPolitics  which tracks individual polls  presidential generals and primaries;  and provides an average poll based on recent poll results.   Biden is up modestly against Trump currently, at least last time I checked.  Both Desantus and Haley were up against Biden in the composite polls not sure by how much.    As I said though,  I don't think polls are meaningful this early in the election cycle.  Both Clinton and Obama who eventually won significantly were down at this stage in their second election cycles.

Comment: "won't be able to campaign in April or March" It's not looking good for the planned March court date, because of the case over his immunity.

Comment: @Barmar,   True, I read an editorial yesterday about the SC might try to speed up the ruling on absolute immunity in order to get away from ruling on the disqualification clause.   Now with two states excluding Trump on the ballot it makes it difficult to avoid or side step procedurally.  With recent scholarship on the debates and intent of 14:3 it makes it difficult for an originalist to contest it's validity in a Presidential election.   But you are correct,  as options narrow it going to all come down to timing.

Answer (score 9):

It is incorrect that there is no Democratic primary for the upcoming 2024 presidential election as there is still at least two people running against Biden in the primary election.

More importantly if voters switched parties to vote in the Republican primary to vote against Trump they would no longer be eligible to vote for any of the other offices in the Democratic primary. While it is true that the race for primary is not in jeopardy of changing there are many other down ballot races that the voters will need to vote on in the same ballot.

[538 poll](https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/polls/president-primary-d/2024/national/)

The latest poll puts Biden at 74%, Williamson at 9% and Philips at 2%

Wikipedia also has this information and lists 3 people in the race as of now

[2024 Democratic Party presidential primaries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2024_Democratic_Party_presidential_primaries)

Also there is no call to not have the primary elections either.

[2024 election dates to know: Joe Biden, Donald Trump and other White House hopefuls face off](https://www.usatoday.com/story/news/politics/elections/2024/01/03/2024-presidential-election-key-dates/72077633007/)

This is a list of upcoming primary dates which includes Democrat ones.

Comment: Sure there is a primary. But at this point it's a mere formality. No incumbent has ever lost a primary and this year as you noted none of the candidates are even close. So its still worth asking the question, why would any democratic voter vote in the democratic primary when their vote would have more effect in the Republican one.

Comment: @Pollman Just because it hasn't happened yet doesn't mean that it won't happen in the future. Not to mention that the amount of support he gets in the primary can impact how voters from other parties see him in the general election and if they decide to support him or not.  But overall the fact remains that there are multiple primary challengers which makes the premise of no primary for the party false and just because  it is unlikely that he will lose doesn't mean that they want to put it to chance.